# How to use php-aop

Tags: php, aop

Documentation is lacking for php-aop. Has anyone used it and know how to do anything with it? I've installed it and set up the include stuff just don't know how to continue.

Lets say i have a class called someclass which has a display method and I want to run some sort of metrics on the display method that will log how long it took in seconds to run. How could this be done with php-aop?

Comment: May I ask why you wouldn't use Traits instead of some four year old code that's not kept up to date?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly...

If you're looking to log PHP execution (essentially profiling) there are tons of questions answering this perfectly well: [profile slow php pages in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039613/profile-slow-php-pages-in-production)

If you're looking for some sort of multiple inheritance solution the PHP 5.4 way is through traits - but my advise is unless you're really sure you know what you're doing there's probably a better way to do it using standard inheritance techniques. This might be through the use of a helper class or factory or some other technique, but it is hard to tell from the information you have provided.